# Semantics verification of an LTL fragment logic

Tags: isabelle, proof-assistant, isabelle-hol, proof-search

I am a beginner to Isabelle and I went over the proof documentation. I am trying to implement a fragment logic of LTL over finite intervals and finite traces called MLTL, the syntax and semantics can be found [here](https://research.temporallogic.org/papers/LR18.pdf) in Section 2.

I used the formal proof for LTL on the archive as a basis (find it [here](https://www.isa-afp.org/browser_info/current/AFP/LTL/LTL.html)). The MLTL fragment is more simple, as a trace is finite. I used the following code in Isabelle to implement it:

```
theory MLTL
  imports Main
begin

datatype (formula_mltl: 'a ) mltl =
    True_mltl                               ("true")
  | False_mltl                              ("false")
  | Prop_mltl 'a                            ("prop'(_')")
  | Not_mltl "'a mltl"                      ("not _" [85] 85)
  | And_mltl "'a mltl" "'a mltl"            ("_ and _" [82,82] 81)
  | Or_mltl "'a mltl" "'a mltl"             ("_ or _" [81,81] 80)
  | Implies_mltl "'a mltl" "'a mltl"        ("_ implies _" [81,81] 80 )
  | Future_mltl  "nat" "nat" "'a mltl"                     ("F [_  , _] _ " [88] 87 )
  | Global_mltl  "nat" "nat"  "'a mltl"                   ("G [_ , _ ] _" [88] 87 )
  | Until_mltl "'a mltl"   "nat" "nat"   "'a mltl"         ("_ U [_ ,_ ] _" [84,84] 83 )
(*Need to define suffix*)

primrec semantics_mltl :: "['a set list, 'a mltl] ⇒ bool" ("_ ⊨  _" [81,81] 80 )
where
  "π ⊨ true = True"
| "π ⊨ false = False"
| "π ⊨ prop(q) = (q ∈ hd π )"
| "π ⊨ not φ = (¬(π ⊨ φ))"
| "π ⊨ φ and ψ = (π ⊨ φ ∧ π ⊨ ψ)"
| "π ⊨ (φ or ψ) = ((π ⊨ φ) ∨ (π ⊨ ψ))"
| "π ⊨ (φ implies ψ) = ((π⊨ φ) ⟶ (π⊨ ψ))"
| "π ⊨ (F [lb,ub] φ) = (∃j::nat∈{lb..<ub+1}.  ( drop j π) ⊨ φ )"
| "π ⊨ (G[lb,ub] φ) = (∀j::nat∈{lb..<ub+1}.  ( drop j π) ⊨ φ ) "
| "π ⊨ (φ U[lb,ub] ψ) = (∃j∈{lb..<ub+1}. ( ((drop j π) ⊨ ψ) ∧ (∀k<j. (drop k π) ⊨ φ)))"


lemma l1:
"([set [p,q],set [r,s],set [s,t]]) ⊨ (G[1,2] (prop(s)))"
  unfolding MLTL.semantics_mltl.simps
```

Towards the end in lemma l1, I try to verify that the semantics is implemented correctly. So I check for the satisfaction of MLTL formula G[1,2] prop(s), for a trace, [{p,q},{r,s},{s,t}]. The first and second elements of the list are sets that contain s, so I know that the lemma holds true. Question: How do I prove the lemma using Isabelle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simp rules for recursive definitions are supposed to be transparent, so you shouldn't need to invoke them for some simple applications. Tools like `auto` and `simp` take them into account.

Actually, trying `apply auto` to see what happens is not a bad choice. We get the following goal:

```
 ⋀j. Suc 0 ≤ j ⟹ j < 3 ⟹ s ∈ hd (drop j [{p, q}, {r, s}, {s, t}])
```

This is essentially trivial, the only missing step should be to realize that you can perform cases/induction on `j` to complete the task.

I came up with a horrible proof by cases at first,

```
apply auto
apply (case_tac "j=1")
apply simp
apply (case_tac "j=2")
apply simp
```

... but you are not supposed to this! For at least three reasons:

1. It does obviously not scale up;
2. It unnecessarily uses **apply** commands when an Isar proof would be better; and
3. It is using a [variable name `j` that was invented by `auto`](https://proofcraft.org/blog/isabelle-style.html), which tomorrow could be called `ja` or something worse.

I couldn't manage to complete a nice proof by hand (I mostly use Isabelle/ZF, not HOL), but by using Sledgehammer I was able to complete it:

```
lemma l1:
  "([set [p,q],set [r,s],set [s,t]]) ⊨ (G[1,2] (prop(s)))"
proof auto
  show "Suc 0 ≤ j ⟹ j < 3 ⟹ s ∈ hd (drop j [{p, q}, {r, s}, {s, t}])" for j
  proof (induct j)
    case 0
    then 
    show ?case by simp
  next
    case (Suc j)
    then 
    show ?case ― ‹Hit "Apply" on Sledgehammer tab here!›
      by (simp add: drop_Cons')
  qed
qed
```

But now knowing that `drop_Cons'` was useful here, I tried **using** that and run Sledgehammer again at the beginning:

```
lemma l1:
  "([set [p,q],set [r,s],set [s,t]]) ⊨ (G[1,2] (prop(s)))"
  using drop_Cons'
  by (smt (verit) One_nat_def atLeastLessThan_iff drop_Suc_Cons 
      insertCI le_less_Suc_eq length_Cons less_Suc_eq
      list.sel(1) list.set(2) list.size(3) list.size(4)
      nat_1_add_1 semantics_mltl.simps(3) semantics_mltl.simps(9))
```

Admittedly, it is not very neat but that came almost without any thinking.

I'm sure there is a shorter way, I leave to the HOL experts to edit my answer!

---

**EDIT**: Actually, using `auto` as an *initial* method is also not very advisable (the goal stated in **show** could change slightly and we would have an error at that point), so one could make explicit that we're proving an auxiliary fact (now written a bit more simply) and *then* instruct `auto` to solve the goal by using that:

```
lemma l1:
  "([set [p,q],set [r,s],set [s,t]]) ⊨ (G[1,2] (prop(s)))"
proof -
  have "1 ≤ j ∧ j < 3 ⟹ s ∈ hd (drop j [{p, q}, {r, s}, {s, t}])" for j
  proof (induct j)
    case 0
    then 
    show ?case by simp
  next
    case (Suc j)
    then 
    show ?case by (simp add: drop_Cons')
  qed
  then
  show ?thesis by auto
qed
```

Comment: Thanks, this works pretty well. After reading this, I tried sledgehammer after proof auto, and that works as well.

Comment: Today I recalled that another suggestion in [Gerwin's Style Guide for Isabelle/HOL](https://proofcraft.org/blog/isabelle-style.html) was that using `auto` as the first step proof is not a very good idea... I'll edit accordingly